# I am trying to push form parameters using bdd cucumber framework but unable to get the values. Please suggest me the changes required

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, bdd, rest-assured

Feature fiel:
Scenario: Verify file upload API
Given fileupload payload
When user calling fileuploadApi with POST https request
Then API call got success with status code 201
And "message" in response body is "File uploaded successfully"

```
public RequestSpecification file_upload() throws IOException
{
    if(req==null)
    {
    PrintStream log = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("logging.txt"));
    req = new RequestSpecBuilder().setBaseUri(getGlobalValue("BaseUrl")).addHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data").
            addFormParam("Name","Annu").
            addFormParam("Size",11).
            addFormParam("Length",1).
            addFormParam("Type","docx" ).
            addFormParam("Priority",2).
            addFormParam("ClientId",18).
            addFormParam("SubClientId",19).
            addFormParam("Comment","no Comments").
            addMultiPart("file", new File("D:\\APItestdocument.docx")).
            addFilter(RequestLoggingFilter.logRequestTo(log)).addFilter(ResponseLoggingFilter.logResponseTo(log)).setContentType(ContentType.MULTIPART).build();
    return req;
    }
    return req;
}
```

getting status code as 500 instead of 201

Comment: Give it a try with removing `.setContentType(ContentType.MULTIPART)` part

Comment: I already used that one